# How to tell Liquibase to ignore the filepath of changelog?

Tags: liquibase

I have a sql-formatted changelog for liquibase. It contains a couple of changesets and each changeset has an uniquie id.

Then I execute liquibase with this changelog file, which reside, say in the directory /home/changelogs. The changes are applied. Then I run liquibase again with the same changelog file. As expected, the changes are not applied this time.

But if I then move my changelog file to say /home/changelog/migration and run liquibase again, the changes are applied.

The liquibase seems to include the path of changelog into decision, if a changeset already have been applied or not.

How can I get liquibase to make this decision only based on chageset-id, not respecting filepath?

Thanks a lot!

JeMo

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use, `logicalFilePath` in the change log.

From the documentation,

> Use to override the file name and path when creating the unique
>   identifier of change sets. Required when moving or renaming change
>   logs.

http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/databasechangelog.html

Should allow you to move the paths, file names etc. around.

Comment: That was really not a clever decision to include the file path.